# Permission denied in CS50

Tags: bash, permissions

I am learning to code in C using this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYierUhIFNQ

We are using CS50 in github.

I have a problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

For some reason colors are not appearing on the words.
Here is what happens in the terminal when I try to compile and run:

```
~/ $ make hello
make: Nothing to be done for 'hello'.
~/ $ ./hello
bash: ./hello: Permission denied
~/ $
```

"Nothing to be done" means that the code is already compiled, right?

And why is it denying me permission to run my simple code?

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l hello*` ?

Comment: unrelated, but you are missing a newline: `printf("Hello World\n");`

Comment: So did you want me to type 1s -1 hello* in the terminal? Because when I do that it says command not found.

Comment: copy and paste from my comment

Comment: Had to use Ctrl + V since it says "Native clipboard unavailable". This is what the terminal says: 

-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 65 Jul 14 20:19 hello

Comment: First this hello does not have execute permission and there's no hello.c, which does not make sense

Comment: Yes, it is strange because I created the file hello.c myself...

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the reason why you don't have `hello.c`, perhaps it was overwritten or deleted.

Also, it's is expected that `make hello` changes the executable permission on `hello`.

Try

```
~/ $ chmod +x hello
~/ $ ./hello
Hello World
```

## EDIT

I think I got it.
You don't have your **C** code in a `.c` file.

You need `hello.c` to be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

then

```
~/ $ make hello
```

and if no errors

```
~/ $ ./hello
```

and you should get

```
Hello World
```

Comment: In the terminal, since the ~/ $ is already there on the left, I just typed in chmod +x hello and the terminal did nothing. I then type in ./hello and I get a syntax error, but the code is exactly as in my first post. ~/ $ ./hello ./hello: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token (' ./hello: line 3: int main(void);'

Comment: Do you want a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try **code hello.c** this worked for me

```
$ code mario2
$ make mario2
$ ./mario2
bash: ./mario2: Permission denied
$ make mario2
$ ./mario2
bash: ./mario2: Permission denied
$ code mario2.c
$ make mario2
mario2.c:7:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'get_size' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int n = get_size();
            ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: mario2] Error 1
```

I just need to fix the get_size function lol

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file first it could be you don't have hello.c because you haven't saved it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541